# Cordova Windows UAP unable to add scaled images

Tags: cordova, windows-10-universal

When adding Images via Cordova config.xml i am able to add images fine. But i'm unable to add scaled images. I've followed the docs and can add these images:

```
<platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/windows/storelogo.png" target="StoreLogo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/smalllogo.png" target="Square30x30Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Square44x44Logo.png" target="Square44x44Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Square70x70Logo.png" target="Square70x70Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Square71x71Logo.png" target="Square71x71Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" target="Square150x150Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Square310x310Logo.png" target="Square310x310Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Wide310x150Logo.png" target="Wide310x150Logo" />
</platform>
```

However I'm unable to add any of the scaled images for each of the images above. The [Cordova docs'](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html) instruction don't work and neither does this format:

```
 <icon src="res/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
```

Has anybody managed to add scaled images via Cordova config.xml?

Also if i manually add the images, Visual studio crashes and doesn't load the project anymore and i have to manually add and remove the platform each time i do a new build.

Answer (score 0):

You set the links for each image like so:

```
     <icon src="res/images/windows/icon/Square44x44Logo.scale-400.png" target="Square44x44Logo" />
     <icon src="res/images/windows/icon/Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" target="Square44x44Logo" />
     <icon src="res/images/windows/icon/Square150x150Logo.scale-400.png" target="Square150x150Logo" />
     <icon src="res/images/windows/icon/Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" target="Square150x150Logo" />
```

I.e. link Square44x44Logo target with the scaled Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png (acutal size: 88x88px)